# Scrollspy selecting wrong element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see in this example, Bootstrap Scrollspy jumps over the navigation but does not really work as it is supposed to. The wrong item is getting the `.active` class.

```js
$('.spycontent').scrollspy({ target: 'nav' })
```

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
}

body > .container, body > .container > .row, .col-xs-6 {
  height:100%;
}
  
.col-xs-6 {
  overflow-y:auto;
}

.item {
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="col-xs-6">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#group1">group1</a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#question1">question1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#question2">question2</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#group2">group2</a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#question3">question3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#question5">question5</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="col-xs-6 spycontent">
                <div class="col-xs-12" id="group1">
                    group1
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 item" id="question1">
                            question1
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 item" id="question2">
                            question2
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12" id="group2">
                    group2
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 item" id="question3">
                            question3
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 item" id="question5">
                            question5
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The menu and content look perfect to me, why is the wrong item highlighted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out what happened:

Somehow the browser did not agree with me when I told it there was a column nested in another column. TWBS CSS somehow messes the position. Removing the nest solved my problem:

```js
$('.spycontent').scrollspy({ target: 'nav' })
```

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
}

body > .container, body > .container > .row, .col-xs-6 {
  height:100%;
}
  
.col-xs-6 {
  overflow-y:auto;
}

.item {
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="col-xs-6">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#group1">group1</a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#question1">question1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#question2">question2</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#group2">group2</a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#question3">question3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#question5">question5</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="col-xs-6 spycontent">
                <div id="group1">
                    group1
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 item" id="question1">
                            question1
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 item" id="question2">
                            question2
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="group2">
                    group2
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 item" id="question3">
                            question3
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 item" id="question5">
                            question5
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```